# Grep : Memory Exhausted on comparing two files to find the delta

Tags: linux, grep

In my project , i am comparing file1 with file2 and the difference will be created in the output_file(delta between the two files). I am using the following command to find the difference :

```
grep -v -F -f <file1> <file2> > <output_file>
```

When i am comparing files around 22MB in size , i am getting the following error:

```
grep: memory exhausted
```

When i am comparing files with lesser size , its working fine.Please letme know if any tweak is needed.

Comment: How much free RAM is in your instance ? If there's nothing then try clearing up some and it should work

Comment: No Luck. I have RAM around 8GB. Freed up some memory.Still shows the same

Comment: What you can do is use `agrep`. However `agrep` gives you approximate matches. The `memory exhausted` error is due to large number of comparisons that you are performing.

Comment: what is your grep version? this might be related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373721/why-is-matching-1250-strings-against-90k-patterns-so-slow

Comment: suggestion: if you are comparing entire lines and if your file is ASCII, try `LC_ALL=C grep -xvFf file1 file2 > op`

Comment: Hi i tried the Suggestion . Process went on for a longer period. Then i need to kill it

Comment: please show a sample of the files

Comment: Please add some lines of file1 and file2 to your question.

Answer (score 0):

you may add swap partition on this machine, so that if RAM is exhausted then, the machine can take space from swap partition. 
here is the link to add swap partition http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/how-to-add-swap-space/?utm_source=feedburner

Answer (score 0):

also you can use `diff file1 file2` command, that will be better option.